# Not able to load Images from pList

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am porting my game on Windows 8 phone. Its already live on iOS and Android.
Its crash when I try to load images from a plist.

Unhandled exception at 0x69B76451 (libcocos2d.dll) in WickedChicks.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000018.

My code is simple:

CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->addSpriteFramesWithFile ("CommonObjects.plist");

My CommonObjects.plist and its png are present in resource folder & is working fine on iOS and Android.

Its giving null for

```
CCDictionary *dict = CCDictionary::createWithContentsOfFileThreadSafe(fullPath.c_str());
```

in

```
void CCSpriteFrameCache::addSpriteFramesWithFile(const char *pszPlist)
```

method.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the .Plist file
Go to Properties.
In the Build Action , set it to "Content"
and in "Copy to output Directory" section , set it as "Copy Always"
Hope this work for you.